# Compare column from one file to line in another

Tags: perl, awk, compare

I have two files which look something like this:

file1:

```
ID1 0 1
ID3 1 1
ID4 0 0
```

file2:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
 a   a   b   b   a
 x   y   x   y   y
```

I want to only keep the columns in file2 whose ID can also be found in file1.
Desired output:

```
ID1  ID3  ID4
 a    b    b
 x    x    y
```

I'm happy with any hints or suggestions in awk, Perl or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl from command line,

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV = pop; @h{ map /(\w+)/, <> } =() }
  @r = grep exists $h{$F[$_]}, 0 .. $#F if !@r;
  print join "\t", @F[@r];

' file2 file1
```

output

```
ID1     ID3     ID4
a       b       b
x       x       y
```

Comment: When I try this on my files it returns a bunch of 0s. I could try to debug the code myself but I find it a bit cryptic. Can you maybe explain how you build the map?

Comment: @codegirl The `map` reads the IDs from file1 into a hash `%h`. The next line gets the indexes of the columns in file2 that have IDs that are also in file1; the indexes are stored in an array `@r`. The last line simply prints the desired columns. Cryptic, I agree (one-liners tend to be).

Comment: Yes, I did indeed not see that the file order was flipped. Now it's working like a charm. And thanks for explaining the code a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you are happy with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR  {ok[$1]++;next} 
     FNR==1   {for(f=1;f<NF;f++)if(ok[$f])p[f]++}
              {for(x=1;x<NF;x++)if(p[x]){{if(length(out)>0)out=out ","}out=out $x;}print out;out=""}' file1 file2
```

- The `FNR=NR` part applies only to the reading of file1 and it records the desired IDs.
- The `FNR==1` applies only on the first line of file2, and it checks if each field is wanted and stores an array `p[]` that says which fields are printable.
- The last sequence prints out the selected (printable) fields, adding commas in between where necessary.